# Is bitshifting from an unsigned to a signed smaller type portable?

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

I have a `unsigned short` (which is 16 bit on the target platforms)
It contains two 8-bit signed values, one in the lower byte, one in the higher byte.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    unsigned short a = 0xE00E;
    signed char b = a & 0xFF;
    signed char c = ((a >> 8) & 0xFF);
    std::cout << (int)b << std::endl;
    std::cout << (int)c << std::endl;

}
```

Is this portable, or am I relying on platform dependent behaviour here?
On all major compilers (gcc, msvc, clang), the result is `14` and `-32`, which is the expected output.

Comment: That's portable. You are just extracting the high and low byte and then storing those bytes in a `char`. (no need to include the `vector` head in the code you show)

Comment: If you want to be extra safe, add some static_assert checking that the size of `signed char` and `unsigned short` are what you are expecting

Comment: Just be aware of the *Sign-Extension* that occurs on your cast `(int)c` to produce the output of `-32`)  The value of `0xE0` has a `1` in bit-7, so when cast to a larger signed type the `1` will be extended in all places to the left of bit-7. (which is how you end up with the negative value in a two's-complement system)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin doesn't the standard mandate the implementation to have Two's Complement?

Comment: @Raildex - Two's complement is required for C++20, but not earlier. However, the compilers you tested have used it always, because of the hardware they target.

Comment: @MartinMorterol -- `signed char` and `unsigned char` are always at least 8 bits; there's nothing that needs to be checked here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am no language lawyer

> Is this portable, or am I relying on platform dependent behaviour here?

Since there is no version specified, I used last draft.

## So what did we need to check:

1. Can `unsigned short` hold `0xE00E` and `signed char` can hold 8 bits?
2. How `a & 0xFF` and `((a >> 8) & 0xFF)` are transformed into `signed char`?
3. How `signed char` is transformed into `int`?

### 1. Can `unsigned short` hold `0xE00E`?

```
Type             | Minimum width 

signed char        8    
short int          16
int                16
long int           32
long long int      64
```

Source : https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental

### 2. How `a & 0xFF` and `((a >> 8) & 0xFF)` are transformed into `signed char`?

> In particular, arithmetic operators do not accept types smaller than int as arguments, and integral promotions are automatically applied

> unsigned char or unsigned short can be converted to int if it can hold its entire value range, and unsigned int otherwise;

Source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion Integral promotion

AFAIU, in `a & 0xFF`, `a` can be an `int` or `unsigned int`.

If `sizeof(unsigned short) == sizeof(int)` `a` will be an `unsigned int` and an
`int` otherwise.

> If the types are the same, that type is the common type.

> If the unsigned type has conversion rank greater than or equal to the rank of the signed type, then the operand with the signed type is implicitly converted to the unsigned type.

Source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion Usual arithmetic conversions

Now we need to go to `signed char` from `int` or `unsigned int`

> Otherwise, the result is the unique value of the destination type that is congruent to the source integer modulo 2N, where N is the width of the destination type.

Source: https://eel.is/c++draft/conv.integral#3

**Note**: is implementation-defined until C++20 (source https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion)

And the memory representation of an negative signed:

> An unsigned integer type has the same object representation, value representation, and alignment requirements ([basic.align]) as the corresponding signed integer type.
> For each value x of a signed integer type, the value of the corresponding unsigned integer type congruent to x modulo 2N has the same value of corresponding bits in its value representation.
> [Example 1: The value −1 of a signed integer type has the same representation as the largest value of the corresponding unsigned type.
> — end example]

Source: https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#3

All good.

```
signed char b = a & 0xFF;
signed char c = ((a >> 8) & 0xFF);
```

Are defined and what you expect.

### 3. How `signed char` is transformed into `int`?

It's https://eel.is/c++draft/conv.integral#3 again. And it wont modified the value.

## Conclusion

> Is bitshifting from an unsigned to a signed smaller type portable?

### In C++20

**Yes**

### Before C++20

The conversion unsigned to signed is implementation defined. To prevent this to happen we need to

```
static_assert(sizeof(unsigned short) < sizeof(int));
```

And the code is fully portable.